# Xubuntu LTS 16.0.4 not recognizing bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I wrote a bash script to alter the touchpad settings using xinput but when I try to run the script I am getting a message saying the file doesn't exist. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# change 'Synaptics Move Speed (278)' mouse speed
xinput set-prop 11 278 1, 15, .05, 40

# change and invert 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance (275)'
xinput set-prop 11 275 -90, -90

# enable 'Synaptics Locked Drags (280)'
xinput set-prop 11 280 1

# change 'Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (281)'
xinput set-prop 11 281 600

# change 'device accel Constant Deceleration (263)'
xinput set-prop 11 263 3

#change 'Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264)'
xinput set-prop 11 264 2
```

the script is called touchpad.sh and when I run 'sudo touchpad.sh', I get the error message:

```
sudo: touchpad.sh: command not found
```

Im confused because I can run each of these commands individually on the command line so Im not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: I just added the error message. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Your script cannot be found by the shell.

The shell looks for files to execute in the folders listed in the `PATH` environment variable. When your script doesn't reside in one of those folder, you need to specify the full path to the file.

For example, if the script is located in your current working directory, you'd call it with

`./touchpad.sh`

Comment: even when I specify the correct path it still returns the same error message

Comment: Did you make it executable? `chmod +x touchpad.sh`

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Still the same error :/

Comment: Is sudo installed?

Comment: I believe sudo is installed but just to make sure how can I check?

Comment: `which sudo` or `sudo --help`, for example.

Comment: It is installed

Comment: Btw, you don't need to run that script with sudo. Please try running it without it and give the exact output of it fails again.

Comment: Are u referring to the chmod +x touchpad.sh command? If so, without sudo it spits out: 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Ok. I think you need to figure out where you put that file before you try to execute it.

Comment: @JoshLowy Where did you save it? If it's lost, you can do a brute force search under your home with `find $HOME -type f -name touchpad.sh`. When you find it, a trick. Since `/usr/local/bin` is generally in the default path (check with `echo $PATH`), you can create a soft-link to you script in `/usr/local/bin` (e.g. `sudo ln -s /full/path/to/touchpad.sh /usr/local/bin`). That way, wherever you call `touchpad.sh` from, it will be found in the default path.

Comment: It's saved on the desktop